# Angular 5 how how to set json response data to a new obj

Tags: angular, typescript

im doing http get of Observable to receive json [(img 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NL27t.png) i want to set this part of as a new obj

```
  getMovies(): Observable<Movie[]> {
return this.http.get<Movie[]>(this.movieUrl);}


 getMovies(): void {
this.movieService.getMovies()
  .subscribe(movies => this.movies = movies); }
```

`export class Movie {
    constructor(
        public title: string,
        public id: string,
        public year: number,
        public genre: string,
        public director: string,
        public poster: string
    ) { }
}`

basically i want to something like this

```
this.movie.title =  item.Title,
this.movie.id =  item.imdbID,
this.movie.year =  item.Year,
this.movie.genre =  item.Genre,
this.movie.director =  item.Director,
this.movie.poster =  item.Poster
```

thanks to the helper

Comment: Please edit your question to make it more clear what it is you want, as of now, it is very unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
`Object.assign({},movies)`
```

Or else use a method which will save the data in this.movies variable which can be used in the entire component.

```
getMovies(): void {
this.movieService.getMovies()
  .subscribe(movies => this.saveMovies(movies)); }

saveMovies(movie){
this.movies = movie;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to map your JSON response to a typescript object then you can use .map() function like:

```
this.http.get("").map(response => <Movies>response.json()); // this will map your JSON response to Movies Class object

this.movieService.getMovies().subscribe(response => {// you will get response as object})
```